# Win 8: window/process moved to 'background process' and I cant move them back to 'apps'

Tags: windows-8, gui, task-manager

I'm having a problem with windows 8. Some windows randomly disappear and I can't access them. They don't show up in the task bar or under alt-tab, but I know the window is still open because I can hear the sound playing and I didn't close it. Under task manager the process shows up under 'Background Processes' but I see no way to move the process back to 'Apps'. If it's a program that shows up in the hidden icons menu I can restore it that way, but otherwise no clue what to do. I'm running a brand new Sager laptop.

Comment: Experiencing this as well,  I'd love to know what's going on. If you add the column Session ID, you'll see it's probably in Session 1 which means it *should* be visible. If you ever figured this out, I'd love to know.